# Program crashes when reading data from firestore to display in an accordion in android

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to create an accordion with the rias and their respective poligonos. To do this I read the two collections from firebase and put them in their respective arraylists (rias, poligonos). It shows me the screen with the rias fine but if I spread the accordion of one of the rias the program crashes and sends this error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference
        at com.luilli.crudpoligonosbateeiros.adapterAcordeon.getChildrenCount(adapterAcordeon.java:32)
```

I have tried manually filling the arraylist of rias and the one with poligonos and the program works perfectly, but if I get the rias and poligonos from firestore the program crashes. The repo is here:[link to repo](https://github.com/palanganero/crudPoligonosBateeiros). It shows a login screen and you can log in with this data: email: natalia.guillan@gmail.com, password:1234567, then you can see the accordion.
And those are the files mainActivity, and adapterAcordeon.

mainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText nombre,ria;
    Button guardar,logout;
    FirebaseFirestore mFirestore;
    //RecyclerView recycler;
    adapterAcordeon a;//el adapter no se utiliza, se utiliza adapterAcordeon
    ArrayList<Poligono> poligonos=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Ria> rias=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Ria> rias2=new ArrayList<>();
    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    ExpandableListView expLV;
    Map<Ria, ArrayList<Poligono>> mapChild;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        nombre=findViewById(R.id.titulo);
        ria=findViewById(R.id.contenido);
        guardar=findViewById(R.id.guardar);
        //recycler=findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        logout=findViewById(R.id.logout);
        mapChild=new HashMap<>();
        expLV=findViewById(R.id.expLV);

        logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                mAuth.signOut();
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, login.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        mFirestore=FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        a= new adapterAcordeon(rias,mapChild,getApplicationContext());
        expLV.setAdapter(a);
        //rias.add(new Ria("arousa"));
        //poligonos.add(new Poligono("vilagarcia","arousa",true));
        for (int i=0;i<rias.size();i++)
        {
            mapChild.put(rias.get(i),poligonos);
            Log.i("rias",rias.get(i).getNombre());
        }
        EventChangeListener();
    }

    public void EventChangeListener()
    {
        mFirestore.collection("rias").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Log.e("Firestore Error",error.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
                for (DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()) {

                    if (dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        rias.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(Ria.class));
                    }
                }
                a.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });

        mFirestore.collection("poligonos").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Log.e("Firestore Error",error.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
                for (DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()) {

                    if (dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        poligonos.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(Poligono.class));
                    }
                }
                a.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

adapterAcordeon:

```
public class adapterAcordeon extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Ria> rias;
    private Map<Ria,ArrayList<Poligono>> mapChild;
    private Context context;

    public adapterAcordeon(ArrayList<Ria> rias, Map<Ria, ArrayList<Poligono>> mapChild, Context context) {
        this.rias = rias;
        this.mapChild = mapChild;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return rias.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
        return mapChild.get(rias.get(i)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Ria getGroup(int i) {
        return rias.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public Poligono getChild(int i, int i1) {
        return mapChild.get(rias.get(i)).get(i1);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int i, int i1) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String tituloCategoria= (String) getGroup(i).getNombre();
        view= LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grupoitem,null);
        TextView tvGroup=view.findViewById(R.id.grupo);
        tvGroup.setText(tituloCategoria);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int i, int i1, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        String nombre= (String) getChild(i,i1).getNombre();
        boolean flag= getChild(i,i1).isFlag();
        view=LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.childitem,null);
        TextView tvChildNombre=view.findViewById(R.id.childNombre);
        tvChildNombre.setText(nombre);
        if(flag)
        {
            tvChildNombre.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_baseline_check_circle_24, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            tvChildNombre.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.ic_baseline_cancel_24, 0, 0, 0);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int i, int i1) {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: at this line in the adapterAcordeon: `return mapChild.get(rias.get(i)).size();`

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you calling `getChildrenCount()`?

Comment: I'm not using it anywhere, but if I don't define it it gives me a compilation error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solver it placing this code:

```
EventChangeListener();
                a= new adapterAcordeon(rias,mapChild,getApplicationContext());
                expLV.setAdapter(a);
                a.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

at the end of the `public ArrayList<Ria> obtenerRias()` function:

```
  public ArrayList<Ria> obtenerRias()
    {
        ArrayList<Ria> r = new ArrayList<>();
        mFirestore.collection("rias").addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                if (error != null)
                {
                    Log.e("Firestore Error",error.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
                for (DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()) {

                    if (dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) {
                        r.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(Ria.class));

                    }
                }
                proceso();
                a= new adapterAcordeon(rias,mapChild,getApplicationContext());
                expLV.setAdapter(a);
                a.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        });
        return r;
    }
```